# Unable to use more than 1 AsyncfileUpload in master page asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Unable to use more than 1 AsyncFileUpload control in a masterpage. 1st control works but second is dead. how to solve..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EMdO.png)

code is

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload_tech" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="Upload_tech" ClientIDMode="AutoId"/>
 <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload_comp" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="Upload_comp" ClientIDMode="AutoId"/>
```

and Cs code is

```
protected void Upload_tech(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string partnoo = Session["partno"].ToString();
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload_tech.FileName);
        string filepath = "~/Uploads/" + partnoo + "/Technical Specifications/" + filename;
        AsyncFileUpload_tech.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filepath));
    }

    protected void Upload_comp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string partnoo = Session["partno"].ToString();
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload_comp.FileName);
        string filepath = "~/Uploads/" + partnoo + "/Complaince/" + filename;
        AsyncFileUpload_comp.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filepath));
    }
```

please help!!

Comment: Please view the image